# past tense of contrive

Tags: meaning, past-tense

So I am looking up the meaning of 'contrive' in google using:

`define contrive`

And it says:

```
Verb
1. Create or bring about (an object or a situation) by deliberate use of skill and artifice.
2. Manage to do something foolish or create an undesirable situation.
```

However when I typed `define contrived`, I get:

```
Adjective
1. Deliberately created rather than arising naturally or spontaneously.
2. Giving a sense of artificiality.
```

I assume `contrived` is a different word altogether. But can it also be used as the past tense of `contrive`?

Comment: If you look at the first link found ( http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contrive ), it lists "contrived, contriving, contrives" as the conjugations of the verb.  This info shows up in the google search summary, you don't even need to click through.

Comment: First thing I thought of was _contrive, controve, contriven_, which would be fun, but apparently is not yet on [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html)'s docket.

Answer (score 3):

The past-participle form of a verb is often used as an adjective.  For example:

- The *written* word
- The *fried* food
- The *contrived* example

The past-participle form of a verb is often the same as the past-tense conjugation (*fried*, *contrived*, but not *written*).  If the past-participle form of a verb is used as an adjective very often, or the adjectival meaning of the past-participle evolves, then it might be listed as its own dictionary entry (like with *contrived* in your example).  Of course, *contrived* is still a past-tense-conjugated verb as well.